# How to set automatic reply with changing issue status into "In progress" as first response in Jira

Tags: jira

We use Jira to handle client issues. When a customer raises an issue, as the first response for issues, we changes issue status into "In Progress" and send reply to customer. I need to automate this procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Jira Workflow post functions to set specific actions that Jira should do when some issue changes its Status.

Here is more details on this matter: https://support.atlassian.com/jira-cloud-administration/docs/configure-advanced-issue-workflows/

Also, you may search for the 3rd party Jira apps that add extra automations here:
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/search?query=automation

Thanks,
Oleh